# GetListItems return the rows with half of the attributes and NOT all?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, caml

I have been searching the web for a couple of hours but still haven't found a fix. I am retrieving data from sharepoint in xml elements but each element only contains some of the attributes and not all. Those missing attributes are not empty as well. Here is the code:

```
var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
            var ndQuery = xmlDoc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "Query", "");
            var ndViewFields = xmlDoc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "ViewFields", "");
            var ndQueryOptions = xmlDoc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "QueryOptions", "");
            ndViewFields.InnerXml = "<FieldRef Name='Title'/>";
            ndQuery.InnerXml = queryString;
            ndQueryOptions.InnerXml = @"<QueryOptions>
                                            <IncludeMandatoryColumns>TRUE</IncludeMandatoryColumns>
                                            <DateInUtc>TRUE</DateInUtc>
                                            <ViewAttributes Scope='Recursive' />
                                        </QueryOptions>";
var result = client.GetListItems(ConnectionDefinition.GetParameterParsedValue("ListName"), null, ndQuery.GetXElement(), ndViewFields.GetXElement(), null, ndQueryOptions.GetXElement(), null);
                return result;
```

Could you please help me if you know why this is happening?
Cheers,
Marji

Here is the xml row that is expected to be retrieved:

```
<z:row ows_Volume_x0020_Unit="mt" ows_Strike_x0020_Unit="CENT" ows_Price_x0020_Unit="AUD" ows_Fee_x0020_Unit="CENT" ows_PdfDownloadLink="http://xxx/Deal Sheets/TGPA200295.pdf, View/Download" ows_SubmittedOnLocal="10/08/2016 10:19:28 (London Time)" ows_Buy_x0020_Sell_x0020_Value123="SELL" ows_Volume123="22" ows_Trader1="Aaron" ows_Submitted_x0020_On1="2016-08-10 00:00:00" ows_Submitted_x0020_By123="mmk" ows_Strike1="432.4" ows_Recap_x0020_Attached123="1" ows_Profile1="APks" ows_Price_x0020_Formula1="CAPQ" ows_Price123="8946" ows_Period1="1/4/16 - 20/4/16" ows_Is_x0020_Complete1="1" ows_Form_x0020_Date1="2016-08-10 00:00:00" ows__x0046_ee123="49" ows__x0044_SN1="TGPA200295" ows_Delivery_x0020_Location123="HHUB" ows_Deal_x0020_Type123="Financial" ows_Counterparty123="Adan" ows_Commodity1="NG" ows_Comments1234="Helloooooooo " ows_Checked123="0" ows_Broker123="GFI" ows_Block_x0020_Trade123="0" ows_Account123="ASI" ows_LinkFilenameNoMenu="T200295.pdf" ows_Author="2241;#Marjan MK" ows_Created="2016-08-10 10:19:32" ows_Editor="1073741823;#System Account" ows_Modified="2016-08-10 10:19:36" ows_ID="294" ows_DocIcon="pdf"/>
```

And here is what is returned:

```
   <z:row ows_Title="T200295.pdf" ows_MetaInfo="294;#SubmittedOnLocal:SW|10/08/2016 10:19:28 (London Time)&#xD;&#xA;vti_parserversion:SR|14.0.0.6123&#xD;&#xA;vti_folderitemcount:IR|0&#xD;&#xA;PdfFileType:SW|http://xxx/images/icpdf.png, http://xxx/icpdf.png&#xD;&#xA;ContentType:SW|Deal Sheet&#xD;&#xA;ContentTypeId:SW|0x010100CFF12A74B6114E438CC39F7B5192A34800F1BA5E970C1C194CB82D536581E235BB&#xD;&#xA;vti_title:SW|TGPA200295.pdf&#xD;&#xA;PdfDownloadLink:SW|http://xxx/Deal Sheets/TGPA200295.pdf, View/Download&#xD;&#xA;vti_author:SR|TGPTRADING\\mmk&#xD;&#xA;vti_documentsigned:BW|false&#xD;&#xA;vti_modifiedby:SR|SHAREPOINT\\system&#xD;&#xA;vti_foldersubfolderitemcount:IR|0&#xD;&#xA;" ows__ModerationStatus="0" ows__Level="1" ows_Last_x0020_Modified="294;#2016-08-10T09:19:35Z" ows_ID="294" ows_UniqueId="294;#{755243DE-93CB-4D74-91DD-A1F0C3CA54A0}" ows_owshiddenversion="5" ows_FSObjType="294;#0" ows_Created_x0020_Date="294;#2016-08-10T09:19:31Z" ows_ProgId="294;#" ows_FileLeafRef="294;#T200295.pdf" ows_PermMask="0x1b03c431267" ows_Modified="2016-08-10T09:19:36Z" ows_HTML_x0020_File_x0020_Type="InfoPath.Document.3" ows_FileRef="294;#frontoffice/TGPA/Deal Sheets/T200295.pdf" ows_DocIcon="pdf" ows_Editor="1073741823;#System Account" />
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample list entry from SharePoint environment and the corresponding output by the code snippet here?

Comment: I just edited my post and added the kind of data that the row I want has and what I receive as a result.

Comment: I just fount out that I could add all the fields I want in ndViewFields.InnerXml and this way I can retrieve what I want.          But I think there should be a better way to do this!!!

Comment: Were you able to solve the problem? Did the answer posted help you?

Answer (score 0):

I was confused by the term 'attributes' used in your question but based on your edit, I understand you are referring to columns in the SharePoint list. If you want all the columns, simply don't use the `ViewField` option. Don't pass any value for `ViewField` (you can use empty string) in the `GetListItems()`.